# Python Pandas: Flag Record That Doesn't Have Unique Identifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to do calculations on data that doesn't have unique identifier to tell the record apart.

| Lot ID | Transaction Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Track In | 1/1/2021 |
| 1 | Track Out | 1/2/2021 |
| 3 | Track In | 1/3/2021 |
| 3 | Track Out | 1/4/2021 |
| 1 | Track In | 1/5/2021 |
| 1 | Track Out | 1/6/2021 |
| 2 | Track In | 1/7/2021 |
| 2 | Track Out | 1/8/2021 |
| 1 | Track In | 1/9/2021 |
| 1 | Track Out | 1/10/2021 |

This is my data set. LotID #1 occurs 3 different times. They are all different instances. I can't use group by because there is no unique identifier to tell those 3 different instances of LOTID#1 apart.

My Question is how do I turn above table into this below output? I also want to create a UniqueID column so I can build reports off of this data as well.

| UniqueID | Lot ID | Track In | Track Out | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lot 1 | 1/1/2021 | 1/2/2021 | 1 day |
| 2 | Lot 3 | 1/3/2021 | 1/4/2021 | 1 day |
| 3 | Lot 1 | 1/5/2021 | 1/6/2021 | 1 day |
| 4 | Lot 2 | 1/7/2021 | 1/8/2021 | 1 day |
| 5 | Lot 1 | 1/9/2021 | 1/10/2021 | 1 Day |

Any help would be so much appreciated!!! Thanks you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a helper column with pivot:

```
#df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) #if needed
h = df['Lot ID'].ne(df['Lot ID'].shift()).cumsum()

out = df.assign(UniqueID=h).pivot(['UniqueID','Lot ID'],'Transaction Type','Date')
out = (out.assign(Duration=out.diff(axis=1).iloc[:,-1])
          .reset_index('Lot ID').rename_axis(None,axis=1))
```

---

```
print(out)

          Lot ID   Track In  Track Out Duration
UniqueID                                       
1              1 2021-01-01 2021-01-02   1 days
2              3 2021-01-03 2021-01-04   1 days
3              1 2021-01-05 2021-01-06   1 days
4              2 2021-01-07 2021-01-08   1 days
5              1 2021-01-09 2021-01-10   1 days
```

Comment: wow thanks! Seems complex but don't mind if I just copy that code snippet!